# weird behaviour doing simple XMMATRIX multiplications

Tags: c++, shaders, directx, graphics, graphics-programming

I have the following function:

```
void AnimatedModelShaderClass::PrepareToDraw(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, XMMATRIX worldMatrix, XMMATRIX viewMatrix,
XMMATRIX projectionMatrix, ID3D11ShaderResourceView* mesh) {

WVP = worldMatrix * viewMatrix * projectionMatrix;
cbPerObj.WVP = XMMatrixTranspose(WVP);
cbPerObj.World = XMMatrixTranspose(worldMatrix);
[...]

}
```

WVP is defined in the AnimatedModelShaderClass class as

```
XMMATRIX WVP;
```

The world, view and projection matrices are correctly received by the function, but as soon as the first line is executed, i can see that WVP contains some very weird values.

If i substitute the first line with the (supposedly) equivalent:

```
WVP = XMMatrixMultiply( XMMatrixMultiply(worldMatrix,viewMatrix), projectionMatrix);
```

then WVP is evaluated correctly and the numbers inside make sense.

Aren't the two ways [equivalent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff621686(v=vs.85).aspx)?
What am i missing?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the multiplications order, it works correctly if i replace the faulty line with:

```
XMMATRIX temp1 = projectionMatrix;
XMMATRIX temp2 = viewMatrix;
XMMATRIX temp3 = worldMatrix;

WVP = temp3 * temp2 * temp1;
```

What's the difference? I don't get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have a solution to my problem, even if i still need time to understand what it does exactly.
The fix is to use the XM_CALLCONV annotation to make sure the function uses the appropriate calling convention, like so:

```
void XM_CALLCONV AnimatedModelShaderClass::PrepareToDraw(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, XMMATRIX worldMatrix, XMMATRIX viewMatrix, XMMATRIX projectionMatrix, ID3D11ShaderResourceView* mesh)
```

This solves my problem, WVP is instantiated correctly. I won't go into details explaining why it works because i don't know it myself. 
For reference, this is [where i got the answer](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/701787-weird-behaviour-using-xmmatrix-variables-inside-a-c-function/), hope it helps!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the order of multiplication. While in regular Maths the multiplication goes from left to right, C++ and to my knowledge other programming languages do it the other way around. With scalar math, this is no problem but with matrix multiplication being *noncommutative* you should switch up the order to make it work with the standard `*` operator while XMMultiply uses an order that from left to right and thus is not suffering from this issue. This means that calculating the MVP/WVP correctly using the `*` operator the calculation should be

```cpp
WVP = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldMatrix ;
```

Yet this does not mean that `XMMatrixMultiply()` is the preferred method as this depends on the style used in your project so feel free to use either the function or the `*` operator as both are equally right.

Comment: matrix multiplication is associative.

Comment: @tkausl Oops, you're right thanks for the heads-up! This logic should no longer be faulty if I'm correct!

Answer (score 0):

Matrix transformations are non-communicative i.e. A * B != B * A.

Consider what you are doing with the matrices:

You are taking something in what is called *model space*, and applying the model, or "world" transform to it:

```
VertexWorld = WorldTransform * Vertex;
```

The result of this is to change the vertex to a new coordinate basis, or change it's frame of reference.

Next you would, for the purposes of graphics, put it into a frame of reference dependant on the camera, or eye (we call this "view space"):

```
VertexEye = ViewTransform * VertexWorld;
```

Now, you want the vertex in screen, or "clip space":

```
VertexScreen = ProjectionTransform * VertexEye;
```

Note the order of multiplication: in computers, statements are evaluated right to left, so the vertex is multiplied by the matrix, then assigned to the new variable.

So if you want to condense this down into a single line of code, you can concatenate the transformations into a single matrix:

```
WVPTransform = ProjectionTransform * ViewTransform * WorldTransform;
VertexScreen = WVPTransform * Vertex;
```

Or:

```
VertexScreen = ProjectionTransform * ViewTransform * WorldTransform * Vertex;
```

Hope that helps you understand.